# Random --> at top of blog

Tags: html

The following characters show at the top of [my blog](https://rtbtestblog.blogspot.co.uk/):

```
-->
```

I've been trying for ages to get rid of them but can't find which section of the html is causing the problem. Could anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Somewhere in your source code there's obviously a piece of a comment left. Can't tell where without seeing your source code though. Did you write the template yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your blog you have commented some styles with `<!-- -->` tag, but style should comment via `/**/` tag.

[image]